# Angular dual-list change scrollbar-track color

Tags: angular, components, angular6

I'm using the AngularDualListBoxModule:

```
import { AngularDualListBoxModule } from 'angular-dual-listbox';
```

and I'd like to change the scrollbar color from blue to Green (pic above).

Actual DualList

[image: Actual DualList]

Actual html code

```
....

<dual-list [source]="mySrc" [(destination)]="xpto" 
  height="191px" [format]="format" key="id" display="nome"
  (destinationChange)="DoSomeThing($event)">
</dual-list>

....
```

How can I do that ?

**The answer**: using Custom DualList ( [link to](https://github.com/czeckd/custom-dual-listbox) ) based in angular-dual-listbox.

Now I can use and configure the custom component in my 'shared' components folders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the custom version they provided? https://github.com/czeckd/custom-dual-listbox

Comment: @HenslerSoftware , I decided to use your sugestion. The custom version provide the change to do what I want. Above, I'll update the topic with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (but maybe not the rightest) way would be to add something like:

### In your component's scss/css file

```
::ng-deep :host scroll-bar-css-selector {
  background-color: green;
}
```

where **scroll-bar-css-selector** it's css selector to that scrollbar.
Of course that style would be global, but its selector would be bound to your component, so it would affect scrollbars only inside your component.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello my friend. Thanks but it doean't work. I tryied to put it in my css componente and in my style.css ( hight level folder/structure). I'll try the  Hensler Software  Solution, downloading and using the entiore and modifield custom component and I'll post the solution here.